# Can't use EGit Plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, git, eclipse-plugin, egit

I want use Control Version for my Programs :) and i decide use Git. I work in Eclipse and Android. I searched and i know, i should install EGit plugin in Eclipse. I add http://www.jgit.org/updates this link in

> install new software

and install `Eclipse Git team provider` and `'Eclipse Git team provider-source code` and `java implementation of git` but when i right click on the project on navigate to `Team-> share Project`, i can't see Git, but i see `tfs-srv/....`! I don't know what is my problem and I need to another thing or not! How can i check that my EGit Plugin install correct on Eclipse.

Thanks for advises

EDIT:

after many searches in google, i see `Error Log`, and on this, i have two Eclipse Git and two java implementation git, i mean i install these twice(this is warning in Error Log ) and i have the error `cannot complete the request. see the error log for details` and on Exception stack trace, write `An exception stack trace is not available.`

Please help me. I install Git on my home computer correct but i can't install on my office computer and this is bad :(

Thanks again

Comment: Be more specific about the problem you have. You can't "see Git", but you could use it.

Comment: No, I install EGit and when i want to install again EGit, wrote this installed before! I see EGit in 'Help->About ADT->Installation Details->Plug-in'  but i don't see in Team and i can't use this. I am confused. please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed TFS before and when i create a new workspace for my Eclipse and first use EGit instead of TFS, my problem solved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to install eGit, it is bundled with standard Eclipse distribution. You probably installed incompatible plugin, uninstall it and try using eGit again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please help me! I uninstall EGit and again install but again i can't see EGit in share project! My Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 (Androdi Developer Tools). after install when i go to 'install New software' in 'http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates ' in EGit plugin i see Eclipse Git Team Provider All Items installed ! but this is not in perspective or anther where ... I think maybee this is for conflict with TFS. How can solve this?!